# how to kill the tty in unix

Tags: linux, unix

This is the result of the `finger` command (Today(Monday) when I (Vidya) logged in)

```
sekic1083 [6:14am] [/home/vidya] -> finger
Name        Tty       Idle   Login Time    Where
Felix   pts/0        -       Thu 10:06  sekic2594.rnd.ki.sw.
john        pts/1       2d       Fri 15:43
john        *pts/2      2d       Fri 15:43
john      *pts/3       4     Fri 15:44
john      *pts/7       -         Thu 16:25
Vidya      pts/0       -         Mon 06:14
Vidya     *pts/5       -         Mon 06:14
Vidya     *pts/6       -         Tue 10:13
Vidya     *pts/9       -         Wed 05:39
Vidya     *pts/10      -         Wed 10:23
```

Under column the `Tty pts/0 and pts/5` are the current active terminals.

Apart from those two `pts/6`, `pts/9` and `pts/10` are also present and I had logged into these last week. But the idle time for them is showing as "-" (not idle).

How can I kill these 6,9 and 10 terminals?

Answer (score 42):

You can run:

```
ps -ft pts/6 -t pts/9 -t pts/10
```

This would produce an output similar to:

```
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
Vidya      772  2701  0 15:26 pts/6    00:00:00 bash
Vidya      773  2701  0 16:26 pts/9    00:00:00 bash
Vidya      774  2701  0 17:26 pts/10   00:00:00 bash
```

Grab the `PID` from the result.

Use the PIDs to kill the processes:

```
kill <PID1> <PID2> <PID3> ...
```

For the above example:

```
kill 772 773 774
```

If the process doesn't gracefully terminate, just as a last option you can forcefully kill by sending a `SIGKILL`

```
kill -9 <PID>
```

Comment: ps -ft is working for pts/5 but not working to kill pts/6 or pts/9 or pts/10. Throwing error for tty 6,9,10: ERROR: TTY could not be found

Comment: Were you able to get the pids for pts 6,9 and 10 ? What is the error reported by the kill command ? Also were there multiple processes listed in the ps output for the same pts ?

Comment: when I execute ps -ft pts/6 error is coming.  ERROR: TTY could not be found.

Comment: ps -ef | grep pts, when I execute this cmd the tty's 6,9 and 10 are not listed. these 3 tty's are coming only in "finger" cmd.

Comment: `finger`, `who` , `w` and other similar utilites pick up the information from `/var/run/utmp` which looks like it might have not been updated correctly when those sessions were closed. Since you confirmed that those sessions are not listed in the output of `ps`, those sessions are closed.

Comment: `kill -HUP <PID>` is often sufficient when the default `TERM` signal doesn't work. I would suggest caution with `-9`, as it does not give any child processes the opportunity to do cleanup.

Answer (score 30):

I had the same question as you but I wanted to kill the gnome terminal which I was in. I read the manual on "who" and found that you can list all of the sessions logged into your computer with the '-a' option and then the '-l' option prints the system login processes.

```
who -la
```

[image: What who gave me]
You should get something like this. Then all you have to do is kill the process with the 'kill' command.

```
kill <PID>
```

Comment: `-n`

where n is larger than 1. All processes in process group n are signaled. When an argument of the form '-n' is given, and it is meant to denote a process group, either the signal must be specified first, or the argument must be preceded by a '--' option, otherwise it will be taken as the signal to send. --- http://linux.die.net/man/1/kill

Comment: Note: -a switch also prints dead processes...so if your trying to figure out who is using all those tty... they aren't

Comment: `kill $(who -la | grep old | awk -F' +' '{print $7}')` worked for me nicely - not sure is safe tho :)

Answer (score 27):

for example kill pts/0

```
pkill -9 -t pts/0
```

Comment: Please try `pkill -HUP` before resorting to `pkill -9` (or `kill -9`). This is often all you need to terminate a tty/pty process, and HUP ("hangup") still gives the child processes of the terminal a chance to clean up after themselves—cleaning up temporary files, for example.

Answer (score 11):

Try this:

```
skill -KILL -v pts/6

skill -KILL -v pts/9

skill -KILL -v pts/10
```

Comment: Or even just ```skill -t pts/6```

Comment: From the manpage: `These tools are probably obsolete and unportable. The command syntax is poorly defined. Consider using the killall, pkill, and  pgrep  commands instead.`

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is with the `pkill` command.
In your case:

```
pkill -9 -t pts/6
pkill -9 -t pts/9
pkill -9 -t pts/10
```

Regarding tty sessions, the commands below are always useful:

`w` - shows active terminal sessions

`tty` - shows your current terminal session (so you won't close it by accident)

`last | grep logged` - shows currently logged users

Sometimes we want to close all sessions of an idle user (ie. when connections are lost abruptly).

`pkill -u username` - kills all sessions of 'username' user.

And sometimes when we want to kill all our own sessions except the current one, so I made a script for it. There are some cosmetics and some interactivity (to avoid accidental running on the script).

```
#!/bin/bash
MYUSER=`whoami`
MYSESSION=`tty | cut -d"/" -f3-`
OTHERSESSIONS=`w $MYUSER | grep "^$MYUSER" | grep -v "$MYSESSION" | cut -d" " -f2`
printf "\e[33mCurrent session\e[0m: $MYUSER[$MYSESSION]\n"

if [[ ! -z $OTHERSESSIONS ]]; then
  printf "\e[33mOther sessions:\e[0m\n"
  w $MYUSER | egrep "LOGIN@|^$MYUSER" | grep -v "$MYSESSION" | column -t
  echo ----------
  read -p "Do you want to force close all your other sessions? [Y]Yes/[N]No: " answer
  answer=`echo $answer | tr A-Z a-z`
  confirm=("y" "yes")

  if [[ "${confirm[@]}" =~ "$answer" ]]; then
  for SESSION in $OTHERSESSIONS
    do
         pkill -9 -t $SESSION
         echo Session $SESSION closed.
    done
  fi
else
        echo "There are no other sessions for the user '$MYUSER'".
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem today. 
I had NO remaining processes, but the remaining finger entry of user "xxx",
which prevent me the deletion of this user using "userdel xxx".

Error message was: userdel: account `xxx' is currently in use.

It looked like a crashed terminal session. So I rebooted, but the issue remained.

```
last xxx
xxx      pts/5        10.1.2.3     Fri Feb  7 10:25 - crash  (01:27)
```

So I (re)moved the /var/run/utmp file:

```
mv /var/run/utmp /var/run/utmp.save ; touch /var/run/utmp
```

This cleared all finger entries. Unfortunately in this way even the current running sessions will be cleared. If this is an issue for you, you have to reboot, after you (re)moved the utmp file.

However in my case this was the solution. Afterwards I was able to successfully delete the user, using "userdel xxx".

Answer (score 1):

you do not need to know pts number, just type:

> ps all | grep bash
>
> > then:
> >
> > > kill pid1 pid2 pid3 ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use killall command as well .

-o, --older-than
              Match only processes that are older (started before) the time specified.  The time is specified as a float then a unit.  The units are s,m,h,d,w,M,y for seconds, minutes, hours,  days,

-e, --exact
              Require an exact match for very long names.

-r, --regexp
              Interpret process name pattern as an extended regular expression.

This worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to close tty for specific user with all the process, above command is the easiest. You can use:

```
killall -u user_name
```

Answer (score -2):

In addition to **AIXroot**'s answer, there is also a logout function that can be used to write a utmp logout record. So if you don't have any processes for user xxxx, but userdel says "userdel: account xxxx is currently in use", you can add a logout record manually. Create a file logout.c like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <utmp.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  if (argc == 2) {
    return logout(argv[1]);
  }
  else {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: logout device\n");
    return 1;
  }
}
```

Compile it:

```
gcc -lutil -o logout logout.c
```

And then run it for whatever it says in the output of finger's "On since" line(s) as a parameter:

```
# finger xxxx
Login: xxxx                             Name:
Directory: /home/xxxx                   Shell: /bin/bash
On since Sun Feb 26 11:06 (GMT) on 127.0.0.1:6 (messages off) from 127.0.0.1
On since Fri Feb 24 16:53 (GMT) on pts/6, idle 3 days 17:16, from 127.0.0.1
Last login Mon Feb 10 14:45 (GMT) on pts/11 from somehost.example.com
Mail last read Sun Feb 27 08:44 2014 (GMT)
No Plan.

# userdel xxxx
userdel: account `xxxx' is currently in use.
# ./logout 127.0.0.1:6
# ./logout pts/6
# userdel xxxx
no crontab for xxxx
```